# Applying data frame name in list to specific column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames, each named according to type. All dataframes have the same column names. I want to apply the name of each data frame to one specific column in that data frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var_a = 1, var_b = 2, var_X = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(var_a = 4, var_b = 5, var_X = 6)
types <- c("typeA", "typeB")
lst <- list(df1, df2)
names(lst) <- types
```

This gives me:

```
> lst
$typeA
  var_a var_b var_X
1     1     2     3

$typeB
  var_a var_b var_X
1     4     5     6
```

What I want it to change `var_x` in each data frame to the respective type.

I tried looping over the elements in `types` to using this to subset to the respective list item:

```
for (i in types) {
  colomnnames <- c("var_a", "var_b", types[i])
  colnames(lst[[i]]) <- colomnnames
}
```

This, however, changes the name of the last columns to `NA`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is in the for loop at this line:

```
colomnnames <- c("var_a", "var_b", types[i])
```

change it to:

```
colomnnames <- c("var_a", "var_b", i)
```